# Cannot open pdf file created by Android app

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am using delphi xe6 for creating the Android app.
Android app is downloading the pdf file from Webservice server as array of bytes. By using TFileStream, created the pdf file and writing the buffer(array of bytes).

But, the problem is pdf file is not creating. And when try to open the file getting error like there is no file.

The pdf file is creating properly if I develop same as desktop application.

Here is the code snippet.

```
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'Sample.pdf', fmCreate or fmOpenWrite);
  try
    FileResponse := GetIFileTransfer.GetFile; //GetIFileTransfer is Webservice object
    FileStream.WriteBuffer(FileResponse.Bytes[0], Length(FileResponse.Bytes));
    Intent := TJIntent.Create;
    Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
    Intent.setDataAndType(StrToJURI(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'Sample.pdf'),
                          StringToJString('application/pdf'));
    SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Perhaps the filestream (or the filesystem) does some internal buffering and doesn't flush immediately. Try releasing the filestream first and then creating the intent and starting the activity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer TOndrej. Even If the Filestream freed before of creating the intent, facing same problem. Any other way to solve this issue? Or Am I doing wrong somewhere saving the files into android tablet?

Comment: Also, use TPath.Combine rather than concatenation.

Comment: Your desktop code is not the same though. This is Android only code. Have you attempted any debugging. Is the file created? Is it valid? Learning these debugging skills will serve you well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answers. I found the solution. Here the changed code snippet

```
    FileStream :=  FileStream.Create(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, 'sample.pdf'), fmCreate or fmOpenWrite);
    try
      FileResponse := GetIFileTransfer.GetFile;
      FileStream.WriteBuffer(FileResponse.Bytes[0], Length(FileResponse.Bytes));
    finally
      FileStream.Free;
    end;
    Intent := TJIntent.Create;
    Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
    Intent.setDataAndType(StrToJURI('file://' + TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, 'Sample.pdf')),
                        StringToJString('application/pdf'));
    SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
```

Comment: reference http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/download-and-open-pdf-file-xe7/2019441